# Android how to delete file in Internal Storage

Tags: android, delete-file

I got file image from Internal Storage. But when i want delete file image not working always return false
My code:

````
var file=File("path_of_image")
        var check:Boolean=file.delete()
        if(check==true){
            
        }
        else{
            // always return false and can not delete file
        } ```
````

Comment: First check existence of file with file.exist

Comment: oh File not exist bro. Why ?

Comment: To make sure the address of the file is correct, first check the existence of the file

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong path.
Use context.getFilesDir for get your app internal files dir
For example:

```
var file = File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + File.separaror + "your_file_name")
```

Comment: i think if path is wrong so an FileNotFoundException will be throw

Comment: @baonq no. File.delete() just returns true or false.

Comment: var file = File(context.getFilesDir(),  "your_file_name")